# Not modifying list in loop but its throwing error Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, generics

I am using following code in c# as below.

```
var result = (from o in db.tblOrderMasters
              join od in db.tblOrderDetails on o.order_id equals od.orderdetails_orderId
              join c in db.tblCountryMasters on o.order_dCountry equals c.country_id
              join cu in db.tblCustomers on o.order_Custid equals cu.cust_id
              where o.order_id == orderid && o.order_active == true && o.order_IsDeleted == false && (o.order_status == 2)
              select new
              {
                 Code = o.order_code,
                 Name = o.order_dFirstName + " " + o.order_dLastName,
                 Quantity = od.Quantity,
                 [...snip...]
              }).ToList();

var Qresult =  result;
try
{
    foreach (var r in result)
    {
         if (r.Quantity > 1)
         {
             for (int i = 1; i < r.Quantity; i++)
             {
                  Qresult.Add(r);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**

As i read other answers related to this error they are saying that you cant modify a list while iterating it, but as in my code i am not modifying the `result` list instead i am changing a new list which is `Qresult` and iterating the main `result list` so why this error is coming ?

one more thing i want to mention here that when i use `quickwatch`  i can see that in result item also added by this line

```
  Qresult.Add(r);
```

but i am adding items in `Qresult` so why item added to `result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to clone this anonymous type `Quantity`-times. Since you cannot modify the collection in the foreach (and assigning the list to a different variable doesn't create a copy), you could use this Linq:

```
var Qresult =  result
    .SelectMany(o => Enumerable.Range(1, o.Quantity)
        .Select(i => new {
              Code = o.order_code,
              Name = o.order_dFirstName + " " + o.order_dLastName,
              Quantity = od.Quantity,
              [...snip...]
        }    
    )).ToList();
```

Comment: if quantity is more than one . then i want to repeat that row . for example if quantity is 2 then there should be two rows , one is original one and other one which we add using code.

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Yes, then use `SelectMany` as shown above.

Comment: +1 and this code creates true duplicates (instead of original code that duplicates only references).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is it possible that for same code with multiple quantity , we can get something like this code-1 , code-2 , code-3 .in your this code. This code works for me as per my requirement but this is new thing which i want in this as addition .

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Yes, the variable `i` in the `Select` already contains the number.

Comment: so can i just i like this Code = o.order_code+i.toString(),  ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Yes, it's coming from [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx). So if you want to start with `0` instead, change `Enumerable.Range(1, o.Quantity)` to `Enumerable.Range(0, o.Quantity)`.

Answer (score 8):

You write :

```
var Qresult =  result;

foreach (var r in result) //result is Qresult
{ 
   .. 
   Qresult.Add(r);

}
```

it's the same like write:

```
foreach (var r in Qresult) 
{ 
   .. 
   Qresult.Add(r);

}
```

So you *change* actually collection

Comment: Exactly, QResult and result are references to exactly the same list

Comment: +1 , You are right and i also know that problem is related to same reference, will you edit your answer with solution to problem .

Comment: +1. @rahularyansharma - it is more or less not possible to suggest solution since it is not clear what you are trying to do. Potentially looks like call to `var repeated = result.Where(r => r.Quantity > 0).Select(r => Enumerable.Repeat(r, r.Quantity ).SelectMany(c => c)`;`

Comment: My comment above is wrong - `Repeat` does not create clones. Also behavior matches original code, it probably not what is OP wanted to do anyway - Tim Schmelter's suggestion on manually cloning seems to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`Qresult` is the same object as result - both references the same object in memory. Do not use anonymous object and create new `List`, as

```
var Qresult =  new List<YourObject>();
try
{
    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        if (r.Quantity > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < r.Quantity; i++)
            {
                Qresult.Add(r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i have to create duplicates in case there is quantity is more than 1.

Comment: Ah missed that you are starting from i = 1, my bad

Comment: i am not able to use var Qresult =  new List<YourObject>(); this as if i cant place result in place of YourObject as that result is anonumus type . you can check on my question also this .

Comment: I know, that is why i wrote that do not use anonymous object. IMO it would be better to use normally defined class in your case.